# Show 1-3 character long text in a speech bubble in Android layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a small speech bubble image. I'd like to place a 1~3 character long string of text inside that speech bubble image. Currently, I'm using a `FrameLayout`, and playing with gravity, padding, and margins. I also played around with a `RelativeLayout`. Is there a better way to do this? I read something about the baseline, but that just aligned the text to the upper-left-hand side of the speech bubble image. Is hard-coding the values, or at least setting hard values in a resource file, the only way to achieve this? Or is there some more dynamic/proper way of doing this? I appreciate any and all help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, is the question related to placing those 1-3 characters in a certain position in the speech bubble image?

Comment: Basically, I'm asking if hard-coding the padding is the only way to properly position the text in the image. I get that some hard-coded values are necessary, but I'm looking for the solution with the least - if any - hard-coded values.